# mac not recognize iphone via usb system information:Current Required (mA): Unknown (Device has not been configured)

Tags: iphone, macos, usb

[image]![system information show like this]
My iphone can not connected to mac via usb. usb port is working and also cable is working. System Information show that "unknow device (...not been configured)". Don't know why this happens?

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: yes. It is related to programming.

Comment: It is related to hardware recognition. How is it related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by installing iofamily kext of snow leopard version of multibeast.

Answer (score 0):

When your device is plugged in, the host is supposed to interrogate it and get the data. One of the parameters is the current the device requests to function correctly. This current can depend on different configurations which the device offers to the host (at least one).

For this to work, there should be a driver installed which detects the request, then interrogates, and makes an intelligent decision on which configuration to select - which makes me think that there is no software which recognizes the phone.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Xcode or Finder does not recognise my iPhone
My Issue: Mac doesn't recognise the device and In iPhone popup to trust my mac was showing every time when i disconnect and connect the device. In finder, my iPhone was showing for a second when i connect but disappears after.

After wasting 2 days on this, I have finally found the solution. Hopefully this helps someone. Here are the things I have tried.

1. Tried stop the USB related program from activity indicator and reconnecting the iPhone. [See this thread][1]. **Didn't work for me** anyway
2. I have tried restarting iPhone and Mac, Cleared Derived Data, Cache and all the things which developer will do to fix this. **Didn't work**
3. Started Follow these two instruction which contain basis troubleshooting apple mentioned. Here's [instruction1][2] and [instruction2][3]. **Both didn't work** for me.
4. Updated iPhone to latest version (17.3.1). **didn't work.**
5. Update Mac to latest OS 14.3.1. **didn't work**.
6. Make sure it's not issue with Cable. My cable and iPhone was working perfectly with other macBook pro. By doing this I was able to come to conclusion that issue is with macBook not my iPhone..
7. Finally I have connected with Apple support(or they call themselves advisors) in a hope to get a solution to this. I was on chat/call with them for 6 hours. They keep transferring to other team and support staff keep asking the same troubleshooting steps which i have already mentioned on the above points. None of their solutions worked. I have mentioned their suggestions below if it is helpful for anyone.
8. Apple Support Team suggested to Logout of current User and create some test user and connect with iPhone which **didn't work**. [Here an link of article on how to do that][4].
9. Apple Support Team suggested me reinstall mac OS(data will still be in mac only OS will be reinstalled which took 2 hour). **Didn't Work**. [Here article link on how to do that.][5]
10. Apple Support Team suggested me to Start Mac in safe mode. Which also **didn't work**. [Article here to follow][6]
11. I'm hope that for at least some of the devs who follows these steps, get this issue fixed on their mac before reach the last step.
12. Finally I gave up with apple support and decided to do Factory reset the entire MacBook after backing up important files to into drive. After formatting the entire mac. After that I have tried connecting with my iPhone and it finally **WORKED**. I have wasted 2 days on this issue. Hope this help someone going through the same.